# PayPal Express CheckOut library for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, paypal

I want to integrate PayPal Mobile Express CheckOut in My iOS application. I had already read out all the PayPal document for it, they tell that for use Express CheckOut, we need to use "**MECL library**". But i did not found library on Paypal so i can't implement it.

Any one have link for this or any related example then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

here is the link [github](https://github.com/azicchetti/MECLPayPalPlugin)

[paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mecl-initializing-iOS/)
download the sdk here both link have that library

Comment: Ok.Thanks kishore for providing exact library, which i want. But i am facing problem in running of application on device. It gives me ""linker command error" "(null): (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPaymentViewController, _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPayment , _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalExpressCheckOutWebView )
" So i am not able to test this due this error .Please help me out.